# package installation failed after installing R

Tags: r

I try to install the tidyverse and tidytext package in R and it gives me the following error

the message is similar in both I would like to know what is the cause and a possible solution

```
ERROR: dependencies ‘hunspell’, ‘tokenizers’ are not available for package ‘tidytext’
* removing ‘/home/yeferson/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/tidytext’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘tidytext’ had non-zero exit status

was installed before R 4.0.0: please re-install it
```

Comment: Is that the entire message? Have you manually altered your library paths at all `.libPaths()`?  The error messages seems like you might be trying to run old versions of packages in a new version of R. I assume you are running 4.0 now? What command did you run exactly to try to install the package?

Comment: hi if i modified with `sudo nano / etc / apt / sources.list`

I have tried the command `install.packages (" tidyverse ")`

Comment: `/etc/apt/sources.list` will impact how the underlying OS installs R packages outside of R, with something like `apt install r-cran-cluster`. `.libPaths()` inside of R impacts where R goes to install packages from within, as in `install.packages("cluster")`. But the two have zero impact on each other.

Comment: in this way? sudo apt-get install r-cran-tidyverse r-cran-bitops does not leave yet

Comment: So why not install the dependencies?

Comment: @IRTFM Could you give me an example?

Comment: `install.packages('hunspell'); install.packages( 'tokenizers')` . Even if you set `dependencies=TRUE` in the `install.packages` call, you will sometimes still see failures  due to dependencies of dependencies. The install.packages function does not do a recursive search for all unmet dependencies. It only does a first level attempt.